# Usercontrols asp.net textbox/validator controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, user-controls, validation

I want to combine a textbox and several validator controls into 1 usercontrol.
Is this possible with the intent to keep some fields dynamic like

textbox:cssclass
textbox:id
textbox:width

I'm asking this because i find myself putting a lot of validator controls
for every (same textbox type) field in my form and it's getting kinda messy.

Kind regards,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your usercontrol with properties that pass through to the textboxes.  So for example, you'd include your ascx like:

```
<cc1:MyUserControl runat="server" TextBoxWidth="50" 
     TextBoxId="txtID" TextBoxCssClass="class" />
```

In the code for your user control, simply create these properties:

```
public int TextBoxWidth { get; set; }
public string TextBoxID { get; set; }
public string TextBoxCssClass { get; set;}
```

And in the code somewhere, pass the properties through to your textbox control.  PreRender would be a good place to do it.

```
...
  myTxtControl.Width = this.TextBoxWidth;
  myTextControl.ID = this.TextBoxID;
  myTextControl.CssClass = this.TextBoxCssClass;
...
```

where myTextControl is the textbox that your usercontrol contains.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot m8 i now get the concept!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.  Feel free to upvote an answer you accept as well, votes help keep us going ;)